# Laravel: Query Many to Many Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app where Users can have multiple Books. I have set up the relation ship and the intermediary table. But the query is not working.

Book Model

```
    public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'book_user');
    }
```

User Model

```
public function book(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'book_user');
    }
```

Create user_book table migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('book_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Books controller I add the book_id and user _id to the table

```
   public function readlist(Book $book)
    {
        DB::table('book_user')->insert(
            ['user_id' => auth()->id(), 
            'book_id' => request('book_id')]
        );

    }
```

In my home controller I try to access the books related to a user but my results return Null;

```
 public function index()
{   
    $user = Auth::user();
    $userbooks =$user->books;
    dd($userbooks);

    return view('/home');
}
```

Comment: How come you have chosen to `DB` instead of the eloquent `attach()` method?

Comment: i think u need there hasmany also

Comment: in your User model you wrote **book** but in home controller you wrote **$user->books**

Answer (score 0):

First rename you `book()` method to `books()` in your User model :)

Then you can try to do this:

```
public function readlist(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::user()
        ->books()
        ->attach($request->get('book_id'));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I now query all the books that are related to a user?

Comment: $your_user->books

Answer (score 0):

User have multiple Books,

Book have multiple Users,

The relationship is **many to many**,
It's better to define the User model:

```
public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'book_user');
}
```

And in your Book model

```
public function books(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'book_user');
}
```

The Doc Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many